# (IDA 7.2) How to Save a section of the database to a new database

Tags: reverse-engineering, bios, ida, bochs

I have a binary file from 1Mbyte that I dumped from an old DOS computer and created a database for reverse engineering the bios. Over the last several weeks I've worked through the upper 256K bytes and created a lot of functions, etc.  I would now like to create a new database from my old database from memory 0xC0000 to 0xFFFFF (Video/System Bios).  Is this possible with IDA and if so what do I need to do?  I wanted to try and use Bochs in tandem with IDA to support my reverse engineering effort.
thanks